# Парсинг даты DateFormat

Tags: java, парсер, simpledateformat

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь распарсить даты формата yy-MM-dd через SimpleDateFormat, возможны невалидные значения типа 20-20-11 или 19-02-49. В случае, если попадают такие значения, всеравно происходит парсинг даты например 20-20-11 в 2020.08.11 либо 19-02-49 в 2019.02.18 , как лучше сделать, чтобы форматы с превышением числа дней и месяцев не парсились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите `setLenient(false)` для используемого объекта `SimpleDateFormat`. В таком случае будет генерироваться исключение, которое Вы сможете обработать как Вам захочется.